# Firefox Mp4 support through extension?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I know firefox does not support MP4 and I understand the reasons for that.  I'm developing an html5 video framework and I strongly prefer firebug to Chrome's debugging tools and because of this, I am very interested if there is any way via extension paid, free or otherwise to add mp4 support to firefox for my personal use.

Anyone know of any tricks?

EDIT:
Clarifying my Question.  I am only testing the html5 implementation while the flash implementation is handled separately.  This is a widget / CMS driven framework and feature parity is not limited to video, so I have to spend a lot of time in the debugger.  A lot of listeners in the video trigger other functionality, leading to very large call stacks.  Because of this, debugging in firebug vs chrome isn't trivial for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, however you can fallback to a flash player that supports H.264, this will also ensure compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me because I'm testing the video itself.  Our platform supports both, but I'm responsible for the html5 implementation.  Looks like I'm stuck with Chrome's debugging tools.
Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released [an extension for Firefox 3.6+](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5-extension-for-wmp-plugin), but it requires Windows 7 and doesn't add some kind of native support, but rather causes similar effect as if you'd use `<embed>` instead of `<video>`.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look at this.